# How to rotate an object's child, when I flip the object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game on unity3d, everything is going great so far and the game works perfectly. But I have one problem. I have add some kind of jetpack on my player, and when the player flips, the jetpack rotation flips as well. As you can see on the images bellow:
[Normal jetpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O92OA.png)
[Upside-down jetpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbNy7.png)
So what I need to do is to multiply the x axes of rotation of the jetpack. But I can't figure out on how to access and change the value from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Quaternion documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) for the available methods.

```
var rotation = jetpackGameObject.transform.rotation;

// edit the rotation here

jetpackGameObject.transform.rotation = rotation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally solved my problem:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EngineController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private bool facingRight;
    private float moveHorizontal;

    void Start()
    {
        facingRight = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        Vector3 rot;
        if (GetFacing () == -1f) {
            rot = new Vector3 (-90, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rot = new Vector3 (90, 0, 0);
        }

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot);
    }

    public float GetFacing()
    {
        if (facingRight) {
            return 1;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```